# How to put C++ source code into beamer slides

Tags: listings, minted, sourcecode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How display LaTeX code in LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/how-display-latex-code-in-latex-document)
>   [How do I fit java style source code in one frame in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58092/how-do-i-fit-java-style-source-code-in-one-frame-in-beamer)

How do I add C++ formatted and coloured source code to my beamer presentations? 
Any simple ways to do this?

Comment: Use `fragile` option for your `frame` and use `listings` package to include and format your code.

Comment: I suggest two answers as reference: [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58927/inserting-tex-code-into-beamer-problem-with-otherkeywords) and [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58092/how-do-i-fit-java-style-sourcode-in-one-whole-page-in-beamer) (referred to Java, but it's the same).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the package [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [minted](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted). Listings is easier to install, as minted needs python, it uses `pygments`, but often produces nicer results.
Also you need to use the `fragile` option on your `frame`, so the content of the frame gets writen to an external file and can be properly processed. This slows the compiling down, so don't use the option where you don't need to!

But remember that the space on the beamer frames is very limited, so you can't (and really shouldn't) get very much code on one page.

Answer (score 13):

You can define the verbatim part before the `frame` environment then you do not need the `fragile` option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\defverbatim[colored]\lstI{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}]
int main() {
  // Define variables at the beginning
  // of the block, as in C:
  CStash intStash, stringStash;
  int i;
  char* cp;
  ifstream in;
  string line;
[...]
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{frame}{A Listings Demo}{C++}
\lstI
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex), specifically the `\pygment` command and the `pygments` environment.  Like minted, PythonTeX requires Python and Pygments.  The highlighted results are saved, so you only need to run Python when you have modified the code that needs highlighting.  Unicode is supported.

You will need to use the `fragile` option for the beamer frames.